# Plotly: What is the tiny horizontal line near its close inside of the candle?

Tags: python, plotly, candlestick-chart

Simple candlestick chart from 4 values, OHLC.

```
go.Candlestick(x=rates['time'],
               open=rates['open'],
               high=rates['high'],
               low=rates['low'],
               close=rates['close'],
               increasing={'line_width': 0.1, 'line_color': 'black', 'fillcolor': 'white'},
               decreasing={'line_width': 0.1, 'line_color': 'black', 'fillcolor': 'white'})
```

What is the tiny horizontal line near its close inside of the candle?
And how to remove it?

Thanks

[line_width=0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUjav.png)

[line_width=1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/na6A5.png)

Comment: I would guess that the mark is indicating the overall movement of the value over the time period (open > close or open < close), made necessary by the fact that you gave exactly the same style for both `increasing` and `decreasing`.  Normally, the direction would be indicated by a hollow vs. solid bar, or two different fill colors.  If you really want to hide this information from viewers, perhaps you can avoid the line by making the two styles differ in some non-visible way - `black` vs. `#000` for the line color, perhaps.

Comment: Is there any reason to set 'fillcolor' to white? If you use a darker color, you won't be aware of the median line.

Comment: black vs #00 is a genius idea but unfortunately doesn't work. Plotly should have option to eliminate it. Even candlesticks are colored, still plot this close sign. you can find it from EVERY candlestick chart provided by Plotly https://plotly.com/python/candlestick-charts/

Comment: What I want is simple black and white body chart. Yes, good for dark colors. but bad for white or any other colors.

Answer (score 0):

The candlesticks in the provided figures are colorless. This chart does not tell us about the bullish or bearish candlestick for a session.The mark provided in the candlestick indicates the closing price for the session.

Thus, if the mark is at the bottom then, the candle is bearish. Likewise, if the mark in on the top then, the candle is bullish.

Comment: Thanks. And how to remove it?

Comment: can you try: import plotly.graph_objects as go, then use fig = go.Figure(your_data), following which try fig.show()

Comment: your_data = go.Candlestick() {Like what you provided in the question}. Later, you can change the color of the candles to black and white using "increasing_line_color=" and "decreasing_line_color="

Comment: Not yet. Changing those line properties affect the close mark too. So as you can see the images I attached, they can't be changed independently.